# DIsplay a view in front of a UITableView with Auto Layout

Tags: cocoa-touch, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

Below is what I am setting up for my view. There is a `mask` (UIView) with `bottom space to superview` of 0. [image]

When I am displaying on the simulator (iphone-retina 4) or on a device(iphone 5) ,the mask is disappearing.However, there is no problem with simulator (iphone or iphone 3.5 ) or device(iphone4)

Should 'bottom space to superview = 0' not let the mask off screen ?

Comment: You're adding this as a subview to a scroll view (the table view) which is usually a recipe for disaster whichever way you do it - it can get messed up if the content becomes larger than the screen. If you do this you normally have to keep modifying the position of the mask in the scroll view delegate methods, are you doing that?

Comment: no, the mask is not a subview of a tableview. Look at the `Object`, you can see `View` contains `Table View` and `Mask`

Comment: So it is! Sorry about that.

Comment: As far as I can tell, you're never seeing the mask. Is that right? This might be a dumb question, but does it have a background color? Can you see it if you remove or hide the table view?

Answer (score 0):

The Auto Layout constraints are fine. The mask won't be displaying because the color is `[UIColor clearColor]`, the `alpha` property is 0.f, the 'hidden' property is set to 'YES', or some other reason such as the view being removed from it's `superview` parent.